# Puxar resultado do mysqli_query usando php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou tentando organizar um ranking com alguns dados do meu DB em MySQL.
Preciso coletar os dados exibidos na Query mas não vem de jeito algum.

Veja a imagem da query com os dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde estou tentando inserir os dados, no caso level e Lider (player_name)

Meu php SELECT:

```
// Player Top Guilds (guilds.php)

        $cron_p7 = '<?PHP $guilds = array(';

        $total7 = 0;

        if ($cron_7=mysqli_query(server_player(), "SELECT guild.name, guild.level, guild.ladder_point, player.name AS player_name, player_index.empire AS guild_empire FROM guild LEFT JOIN player ON player.id = guild.master LEFT JOIN player_index ON player_index.id=player.account_id ORDER BY guild.ladder_point DESC, guild.name ASC;"))

            while ($cron_r7=mysqli_fetch_object($cron_7)){

                $total7++;

                $empr = ($cron_r7->guild_empire)?$cron_r7->guild_empire:1;

                $cron_p7 .= ' '.$total7.' => ["'.$cron_r7->name.'", '.$empr.', '.$cron_r7->ladder_point.'],';

            }

        $cron_p7 .= ');';

        $cron_f7 = fopen(s('cron')."guilds.php", "w");

        fwrite($cron_f7, $cron_p7);

        fclose($cron_f7);

        echo "Cron Ejecutado <b>guilds.php</b>...<br>\n";
```

Meu php com os resultados:

```
<?PHP $start_count += 10; } ?>
    </div>
    <table id="full_ranking_table">
        <tr class="full_ranking_table_titles_row">
            <td class="full_ranking_table_title_position">#</td>
            <td class="full_ranking_table_title_name"><?=l(52);?></td>
            <td class="full_ranking_table_title_name_lider">Level</td>
            <td class="full_ranking_table_title_name_lider">Lider</td>
            <td class="full_ranking_table_title_kingdom"><?=l(53);?></td>
            <td class="full_ranking_table_title_points"><?=l(57);?></td>
        </tr>
<?PHP for($i = $start + 1; $i <= $stop; $i++){ ?>
        <tr class="full_ranking_table_row <?=($i == GPage(4))?"highlighted_playername":"";?>">
            <td id="p<?=$i;?>" class="full_ranking_rank <?=($i>5)?"":"top_rank";?>"><?=($i>5)?$i:"";?></td>
            <td class="full_ranking_playername"><?=$guilds[$i][0];?></td>
            <td class="full_ranking_playername"><?=$guilds[$i][1]?></td>
            <td class="full_ranking_playername"><?=$guilds[$i][1]?></td>
            <td class="full_ranking_<?=$guilds[$i][1]?>_kingdom"></td>
            <td class="full_ranking_points"><?=$guilds[$i][2]?></td>
        </tr>
<?PHP } ?>
```

Veja o exemplo do ranking:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: esta  `<?=$guilds[$i][1]?>` no campo que deveria conter o id da coluna por que eu não consigo chegar no ID correto, e coloquei como exemplo. Já tentei usar um `print_r($guilds)` para tentar localizar as informações e não puxa os dados.

Comment: No inicio você faz `$cron_p7 = '<?PHP $guilds = array(';` e logo em seguida você sobrescreve `$cron_p7` com `if ($cron_7=mysqli_query(...` e continua a sobrescrever `$cron_p7` em `while ($cron_r7=mysqli_fetch_object($cron_7)` você tem criar variáveis próprias para receber esses objetos.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica consegui fazer :)

$cron_p7 .= ' '.$total7.' => ["'.$cron_r7->name.'", '.$empr.', '.$cron_r7->ladder_point.', "'.$cron_r7->player_name.'", "'.$cron_r7->level.'"],';

Answer (score 0):

Como o Augusto me guiou bastava um novo campo na variavel onde eu estava errando.

Correto seria:

```
$cron_p7 .= ' '.$total7.' => ["'.$cron_r7->name.'", '.$empr.', '.$cron_r7->ladder_point.', "'.$cron_r7->player_name.'", "'.$cron_r7->level.'"],';
```